# understanding spring boot and hibernate interaction

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I'm newbie to JPA world and have a misunderstanding of JPA and HIBERNATE and its relationships with Spring Data, can you guys tell me is the Spring Data is a specification like JPA or a implementation of JPA, if this is true where is HIBERNATE ? and why we have this (springframwork)

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
```

instead of HIBERNATE import? where do we call JPA interface?
NB : i'm based on [this articale](http://tothought.com/post/2)

thank you in advance ...

Answer (score 1):

JPA is a specification for object-relational mapping.

Hibernate is an implementation of this specification.

Spring-data-JPA is an abstraction on top of JPA simplifying the writing of repositories, i.e. classes that use the JPA API to get, save, delete and query JPA entities.

You can of course learn more by simply reading [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/)

Comment: I read the tutorial of spring data (https://spring.io/blog/2011/02/10/getting-started-with-spring-data-jpa) , but based on this tutorial (http://tothought.com/post/2) my question is : is this what you are calling 'abstraction on top of JPA' is another specification, who implements JPA ??

Comment: No, it's not a specification (or I would have said so), and it's not JPA, since it is another abstraction, sitting on top of JPA.

Comment: thank you for responding me, but what do you mean by abstraction?

Comment: OK, let's take an example. You could send and receive HTTP messages by just using low-level sockets. But it's way easier to use an HttpClient class, which provides an abstraction over the HTTP protocol, i.e. a class, with  methods like get(), post() which allow sending GET and POST requests. The idea is basically the same here. Spring-data-jpa provides higher level tools to make it easier to work with JPA.

Comment: thank you, i understand now, but where is the role of hibernate here?

Comment: It provides the implementation of the JPA specification. As I said in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

To explain with a bit of history.

**Stage 1** : Initially all database operations were done in code using jdbc with sql statements.
**Problem 1:** Changing underlying database was a big problem, because this would require huge code changes, because we were using
 sql statements particular to the database in use(Tight coupling)
**Solution 1:** Come up with a ORM model, which would help in replacing databases with ease.

**Stage 2:** We had different ORM's like Hibernate, IBatis etc, which helped us in replacing databases at ease.
**Problem 2:** If we had to change the ORM's itself(not database), we had the same problem again.
**Solution 2:**  Come up with a specification for any persistance API or ORM's

**Stage 3:** JPA solved the problem which we had previously.
**Problem 3:** Now its the era of Nosql databases. Now we had the same problem again, what if we have to switch databases
from sql to nosql and vice versa(because **JPA is only for Relational databases**)
**Solution 3:** In came spring-data which solved this problem. Which provided higher level of abstraction.
spring-data provides different modules.

spring-data-jpa for relational databases

spring-data-mongodb for Mongo
spring-data-redis for redis
spring-data-cassandra for cassandra

[image]

Now to the question of where you are specifying Hibernate in your case.

Since you are using spring-boot(which is opinionated), it takes hibernate as default ORM to talk to database(relational). If you want some other ORM to use, you have to configure it manually.

Comment: thank you @pvpkiran for your response, tell me about the version of hibernate used with spring-boot , is it a custom version used just for spring-boot ? because hibernate can't interact with spring data directly.

Comment: there is no custom version. The version of hibernate depends on your spring-data-jpa version.

Comment: what do you meant by "hibernate can't interact with spring data directly" ? spring-data(spring-data-jpa) is an abstraction on top of JPA which is an abstraction on top of Hibernate

Comment: do you mean that spring-data is an abstraction on top of jpa and hibernate , both elements are used by spring-data?

Comment: checkout the picture I added. May be its helpful

Comment: `Now its the era of Nosql databases`. LOL. "NoSQL databases" exist, yes. but their usage is dwarfed by RDBMS, and many of these "NoSQL databases" no longer have much usage at all. And Spring Data did not "solve" anything to do with persistence to these databases, since Spring Data simply provides access to the low level API of that database. And that part is, of course, nothing to do with the question to be answered

Comment: What I meant by era of nosql databases is , we have so many new nosql databases these days in the market, I didnt mean that they are most widely used.  "Spring Data simply provides access to the low level API of that database"---> Of course this is what was needed. Lets say if you are using mongodb and wantt to use some other nosql tomorrow, It is a matter of seconds to do that, if you are using spring-data